# Error: Platform 'nodejs' version '14.17.1' is unsupported

Tags: node.js, angular, azure, github-actions, oryx

I am trying to deploy Angular application to Azure. I created a static web app in Azure, and connected it to my Github main branch. When I run the action to deploy the app, I am getting an error in Build and Deploy action as Platform 'nodejs' version '14.17.1' is unsupported.

Here is the snippet of the error message:

```
Operation performed by Microsoft Oryx, https://github.com/Microsoft/Oryx
You can report issues at https://github.com/Microsoft/Oryx/issues

Oryx Version: 0.2.[20](https://github.com/nimeshshrestha/autoglasslocator-admin-ui-v01/runs/7714362605?check_suite_focus=true#step:5:21)220401.1, Commit: afed4f696a08bfd4c8e4109704a082bf9fb20515, ReleaseTagName: 20220401.1

Build Operation ID: |ZIeL+T275t4=.afcbd56a_
Repository Commit : 848b07de657ce2303e1469a882d68999bed7925a

Detecting platforms...
Error: Platform 'nodejs' version '14.17.1' is unsupported. Supported versions: 10.1.0, 10.10.0, 10.12.0, 10.14.2, 10.16.3, 10.18.0, 10.18.1, 10.19.0, 10.20.0, 10.20.1, 10.[21](https://github.com/nimeshshrestha/autoglasslocator-admin-ui-v01/runs/7714362605?check_suite_focus=true#step:5:22).0, 10.[22](https://github.com/nimeshshrestha/autoglasslocator-admin-ui-v01/runs/7714362605?check_suite_focus=true#step:5:23).0, 10.22.1, 10.[23](https://github.com/nimeshshrestha/autoglasslocator-admin-ui-v01/runs/7714362605?check_suite_focus=true#step:5:24).0, 10.[24](https://github.com/nimeshshrestha/autoglasslocator-admin-ui-v01/runs/7714362605?check_suite_focus=true#step:5:25).1, 12.11.0, 12.11.1, 12.12.0, 12.13.0, 12.14.0, 12.14.1, 12.16.0, 12.16.1, 12.16.2, 12.16.3, 12.18.0, 12.18.1, 12.18.2, 12.18.3, 12.18.4, 12.19.0, 12.20.0, 12.21.0, 12.22.0, 12.22.11, 12.22.4, 12.22.6, 12.22.9, 12.9.1, 13.9.0, 14.0.0, 14.1.0, 14.10.0, 14.10.1, 14.11.0, 14.12.0, 14.13.0, 14.13.1, 14.14.0, 14.15.0, 14.15.1, 14.16.0, 14.17.0, 14.17.4, 14.17.6, 14.18.3, 14.19.1, 14.2.0, 14.3.0, 14.4.0, 14.5.0, 14.6.0, 14.7.0, 14.8.0, 14.9.0, 15.0.0, 15.0.1, 15.1.0, 15.2.0, 15.2.1, 15.3.0, 16.13.1, 16.13.2, 16.14.0, 16.14.2, 16.5.0, 16.6.1, 16.8.0, 17.0.1, 17.1.0, 17.2.0, 17.3.1, 17.4.0, 17.5.0, 17.6.0, 4.4.7, 4.5.0, 4.8.0, 4.8.7, 4.9.0, 4.9.1, 6.10.3, 6.11.0, 6.11.5, 6.17.1, 6.2.2, 6.6.0, 6.9.3, 6.9.5, 8.0.0, 8.1.4, 8.11.2, 8.11.4, 8.12.0, 8.15.1, 8.16.1, 8.16.2, 8.17.0, 8.2.1, 8.8.1, 8.9.4, 9.4.0, 1.17.3, 1.18.0, 1.19.0, 1.19.1, 1.19.2, 1.20.0, 1.21.0, 1.21.1, 1.22.0, 1.22.1, 1.22.2, 1.22.4


---End of Oryx build logs---
Oryx has found build steps, but identified unsupported platform versions. Failing build.
I have tried to use setup-node action by following this link: https://github.com/actions/setup-node.
```

I edited the yml file, and added this:

```
steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - uses: actions/setup-node@v3 ### Added this line
        with:
          submodules: true
          node-version: 16 ### Added this line
```

I have also looked at this issue: https://github.com/microsoft/Oryx/issues/650. But there is nothing that is helpful.

EDIT: I have also posted the question here https://github.com/microsoft/Oryx/issues/1504

Comment: Please mention that you're cross-posting: https://github.com/microsoft/Oryx/issues/1504

Comment: I have resolved the issue by updating the node version in my angular app. I went to package.json, and updated node version to 14.17.6. And it worked after that.